# Colour different objects in mask image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I created a unet to segment each pixel if it object or not, mask image.
The output is the following:

**Crypt segmentation**

[image: crypt segmentation]

My goal is to convert this image that each object (the white pixels) will be colour in different colour
like the following:

**Instance object**

[image: instance object]

Can anyone help me on how to approach this?

Extra infomation:
The unet that implemented:

```
    def get_unet(self):
    inputs = Input((self.img_rows, self.img_cols,1))
    conv1 = Conv2D(64,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(128,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(256,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(512,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(drop5)
    up6 = Conv2D(512,
                2,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(up6)
    merge6 = Concatenate(axis=3)([drop4, up6])
    conv6 = Conv2D(512,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6)
    up7 = Conv2D(256,
                2,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(up7)
    merge7 = Concatenate(axis=3)([conv3, up7])
    conv7 = Conv2D(256,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7)
    up8 = Conv2D(128,
                2,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(up8)
    merge8 = Concatenate(axis=3)([conv2, up8])
    conv8 = Conv2D(128,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8)
    up9 = Conv2D(64,
                2,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(up9)
    merge9 = Concatenate(axis=3)([conv1, up9])
    conv9 = Conv2D(64,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64,
                3,
                activation='relu',
                padding='same',
                kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)
    # conv9 = Conv2D(2,
    #           3,
    #           activation='relu',
    #           padding='same',
    #           kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)

    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv10)
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4),
                loss='binary_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()

    return model
```

The input image is as following:
[image: input image]

The label data is as following:
[image: label image]

While searching for a solution I cross by this post:
[How to color objects in an image with different color each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783969/how-to-color-objects-in-an-image-with-different-color-each)
Unfortunately I got results that are not satisfying like the following:
[image: result of object]

```
colors = [(0,0,0)] + [(random(),random(),random()) for i in range(255)]
im = imageio.imread(path + '6.jpg')

new_map = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('new_map', 
colors, N=256)
blobs, number_of_blobs = ndimage.label(im)
plt.imshow(blobs, cmap=new_map)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You should say, or provide links as to what `unets` and `crypts` are please. Is your actual issue with thinking up some unique colours? Or with selecting individual objects? Or with the actual colouring? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell I edited my question. Please let me know if any more information needed. Thanks in advance